# Refer to a parent movieclip with tweenLite

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have a movieclip called `cerrarSumInfo` inside a movieclip called `SumInfo`, `cerrarSumInfo` removes `SumInfo` from stage.

Code: (on the `SumInfo` timeline)

```
cerrarSumInfo.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, cerrarSum);

function cerrarSum(e:MouseEvent):void
{
        this.parent.removeChild(this);
        TweenLite.to(buscador, 0.7, {x:14, y:354.95});
}
```

`buscador` is on the main timeline, so when i test i get:

> ```
> Access of undefined property buscador.
> ```

How can i reference `buscador` from `sumInfo`?

I Solved:

I solved it, all the problem was because:

```
this.parent.removeChild(this);
TweenLite.to(buscador, 0.7, {x:14, y:354.95});
```

Y was removing the child before the tween, and yes, a i reffer to buscador with:

```
MovieClip(root).buscador;
```

thanks!

Comment: nowhere do you explain what `buscador` is?

Comment: Sorry, buscador it's a movieclip on the stage that contains a navbar

Comment: Ok, when you say on the stage you mean the main timeline?  and where is the code shown? also main timeline?

Comment: Yes, i mean the main timeline, and this code is inside suminfo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There a few ways you can get a reference to `buscador` from inside `suminfo`.  Here are two such ways:

1. use the `root` keyword to get a reference to the main timeline.

   ```
   MovieClip(root).buscador;
   ```
2. Use the `parent` keyword:

   ```
   MovieClip(parent.parent).buscador; //one parent up is cerrarSumInfo, two parents up should be the main timeline
   ```

---

A cleaner way would be to use events:

1. Take the tween out of this function:

   ```
   function cerrarSum(e:MouseEvent):void
   {
       this.parent.removeChild(this);
   }
   ```
2. Then, on the main timeline:

   ```
   sumInfo.addEventListener(Event.REMOVED_FROM_STAGE, sumInfoRemoved); //listen for when sumInfo is removed

   function sumInfoRemoved(e:Event):void {
       TweenLite.to(buscador, 0.7, {x:14, y:354.95});
   }
   ```

Comment: I get Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference. about buscador

Comment: And for sure there is a movieClip on the stage with that instance name `buscador` when you check via Properties window? It's not inside another movieClip?